# How can I write a test where I check if the view visibility is gone in Robolectric?

Tags: android, robolectric

In Robolectric if I want to check if the view is visible I can do the following
  `onView(Matchers.allOf(withId(R.id.btn_action))).check(matches(isDisplayed()))`
wondering what if the view visibility is gone, how can I check it in test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

`onView(Matchers.allOf(withId(R.id.btn_action))).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))`

Or

`onView(Matchers.allOf(withId(R.id.btn_action))).check(doesNotExist())`